# Get image from SDcard filter using startWith

Tags: android

I'm stack with how to get image from SDcard folder which image name start with ("2.") 
here is my code:

```
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();
        // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
        FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
        // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
        FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            // Get the path of the image file
            FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            // Get the name image file
            FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();

if(( FileNameStrings[i].substring( 0, 1 ) ).equalsIgnoreCase( "2" ) )
{
    //This filename starts with 2
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ErAcube for your replay... your code I get all images, but i need get all images which start with number 2 only.

Comment: inside the if block if you check String fName = fileNameStrings[i]; then you will get the desired fileName.

Comment: I have tried everything bu unfortunately unsuccessful...I'm following this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-display-images-from-sd-card-tutorial/